# How do I include a header in a generated table of my javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I receive in my javascript a json data that it is converted to a html table.

The script is working.. but how do I include a header in my table?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#id_adv').DataTable();
            $('#id_adv').on('click','.btn',function(){
                var currow = $(this).closest('tr');
                var result = currow.find('td:eq(1)').text();

                $.get('{% url "prop_table" %}', {var1:result}, function (data_prop) {
                    var data = data_prop['data_prop']       
                    var data_json = JSON.parse(data);
                    var html = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data_json.length; i++) {
                        html +=  "<tr><td>" + data_json[i].fields.var1 + "</td><td>" + data_json[i].fields.var2 + "</td><tr>";
                        }
                    $('#id_prop').html(html);                      
                })
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = result;                    
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using `eval()` and not `JSON.parse()`?!

Comment: It was not workin with JSON.parse()

Comment: what about `table.createTHead()` ?

Comment: If `JSON.parse()` doesn't work, you don't have valid JSON. Stop right there and correct that. `eval()` is, at best, poor performing and, at worst a gaping security hole. It should rarely, if ever be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight modification to your existing code to add a header. (I've cut out your usage of eval and just kept in the relevant part to create the HTML table header)

```
<script>
        ....
                    var html = "";
                    html +=  "<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><tr>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data_json.length; i++) {
                        html +=  "<tr><td>" + data_json[i].fields.var1 + "</td><td>" + data_json[i].fields.var2 + "</td><tr>";
                        }
                    $('#id_prop').html(html);                      
        ....
</script>
```

This should add a header to your table.
And I agree with the comment in your question, use the built in JSON parsing. `eval` is just asking to be exploited.

Comment: Please remove the eval in your example code. People are going to copy and paste your code

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can add the header after create the table. The createTHead() method creates an empty  element and adds it to the table. I.e.:

```
<script>
    function createHeader() {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var header = table.createTHead();
        var row = header.insertRow(0);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = "<b>This is a table header</b>";
    }
</script>
```